Order of elements in account_infos in invoke()
Is order of elements in account_infos in invoke(instruction: &Instruction, account_infos: &[AccountInfo]) important?
I thought it is important because programs written in native rust reads account infos sequentially, but when testing transfer function from system_program i get same behavior:
let transfer_instruction = system_instruction::transfer(user.key, &fundraising_account.key(), amount);

 solana_program::program::invoke(
     &transfer_instruction,
     &[
         ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info(),
         fundraising_account.to_account_info(),
     ],
 )?;

same behavior as
 solana_program::program::invoke(
     &transfer_instruction,
     &[
         fundraising_account.to_account_info(),
         ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info(),

     ],
 )?;


This is a great question -- in my years of developing Solana on-chain programs, I always thought that the order of the account infos mattered in invoke, but it doesn't! I tested changing the order of account infos in this simple program to prove it to myself: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/27f0fcecca67a8a23bf1efcbf6315930c00883ce/examples/rust/transfer-tokens/src/processor.rs#L66
The instruction defines the order in which the account infos will be provided to the callee program (the one targeted with the CPI), and the account infos slice is just the "universe" of accounts that can be used for the CPI.
This is just another data point showing that it's silly to require the account infos in invoke, and we should create a new syscall that omits the account infos.

How does the callee program know which account info corresponds to which account if I can pass account infos in a random order? Also, why can I omit the system program account info and it still works?

The account infos are passed to the callee in the order defined by the instruction, and not the account infos. And you can omit the callee program just to make things simpler -- that part was changed back in 2020 :-) here's some more reading about relaxing it even further in the future: https://github.com/solana-foundation/solana-improvement-documents/blob/main/proposals/0163-lift-cpi-caller-restriction.md

Yes, the order of account_infos in invoke matters because instructions rely on the accounts being passed in the exact order they expect. For system_instruction::transfer, the first account should be the source (payer), and the second should be the destination. Swapping them might not always cause an immediate error in simple programs like transfer, but it's still incorrect and could lead to issues with other programs or instructions. Always follow the expected order.
Correct example:
solana_program::program::invoke(
    &transfer_instruction,
    &[  
        ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info(), // Source (payer)
        fundraising_account.to_account_info(), // Destination
    ],
)?;


This is not a very precise answer; it either should work or shouldn't. The relevant code is here if anyone wants to take a look: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/master/programs/bpf_loader/src/syscalls/cpi.rs#L1070 - there are instruction accounts and account infos.
